# DAX FORMAT function cause cartesian product on Power BI visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following SSAS Tabular model defined:

[image]

On the **Product** table, I have the following measures defined:

1. `DeliveryQty2018:=    CALCULATE ( SUM ( PurchaseDelivery[PurchaseOrderQuantity] ), ( PurchaseEstimatedWarehouseArrivalDate[PurchaseEstimatedWarehouseArrivalYear] = 2018 ) )`
2. `DeliveryQty2019:=    CALCULATE ( SUM ( PurchaseDelivery[PurchaseOrderQuantity] ), ( PurchaseEstimatedWarehouseArrivalDate[PurchaseEstimatedWarehouseArrivalYear] = 2019 ) )`
3. `Sum DeliveryQty 2018-2020: = FORMAT([DeliveryQty2018] + [DeliveryQty2019] + [DeliveryQty2020],"# ### ###")`

I'm creating a table visual on my Power BI report, that consists of the following fields:

[image]

This combinations gives me a cartesian product of: **Product X ProductCategory**:

[image]

What's interesting, when I remove the **FORMAT()** wrapper for the **Sum DeliveryQty 18-20**, cartesian product is removed and I achieve the single record I was loooking for. However, if I remove the ProductCategory field and leave the **Sum DeliveryQty 18-20** measure with the **FORMAT()** function in place I also get the single record..

Can anyone explain to me what's going here in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FORMAT turns blanks (nulls) into empty strings `""` rather than proper blanks, so you probably want to check for that first before formatting.

```
Sum DeliveryQty 2018-2020: =
VAR Qty = [DeliveryQty2018] + [DeliveryQty2019] + [DeliveryQty2020]
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( Qty ), BLANK(), FORMAT ( Qty, "# ### ###" ) )
```

Comment: I'm quite a novice to PowerBI, so this might sound like asking for something that is fundamental to tabular modelling, but why for these blanks evaluated to an empty string using the FORMAT() syntax I get multiple categories then?

EDIT

Even if I apply a page-scope filter to a single, specific SKU?

Comment: In your model, ProductCategory filters Product but not vice versa, so specifying SKU doesn't propagate "upstream" the 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: So even if I apply filter on SKU, still all Product Categories are "passed" to the PurchaseDelivery table? So why there are blanks for them? - it is becasue still there is a specific SKU filter passed to PurchaseDelivery that take the precedence over all the categories passed from the ProductCategory?

Comment: Right. Since category is not filtered, you get all of them. All of the ones not associated with your chosen SKU result in blanks that are ordinarily suppressed but show up because of FORMAT.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Solution you proposed works perfectly! 
However, I'm still not sure, why removing the measure from the visual and filtering page to specific SKU does not give me this cartesian product...

Comment: Again, I'm in a situation, when would like to show ,'Product'[SKU],ProductCategory[ProductCategoryFullName],[# SomeMeasure] on my report. User requested me that [# SomeMeasure] should return a string description in case it evaluates to blank, like "NA". By applying this requirement to the measure definition, I got the cartesian product. Is there any modelling / coding technique that would let me to get non-multplicated rows with this measure always evaluating to explicit value?

Comment: I think you should write a new question that carefully lays out where you want to have blanks versus where you want "NA".