# Microsoft Power BI - DAX - tricky situation involving ALLSELECTED in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, slicers

I have a situation below in [Power BI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NYCypgZV8OgCrzWy7By_EEQGcoglJpYU/view?usp=sharing) and DAX language.

I have 2 simple tables:

1. CountryTable
2. YearTable

There is a 1-M relationship between YearTable and CountryTable.

[image]

[image]

The latter (Year) is used to feed values into a slicer.

The former (Country) is the main table, with just 4 rows.

These two tables are related via the Year column.

The Year slicer always has EXACTLY 2 values chosen in my Power BI report.

I need the Maximum of these two values of the year slicer as a measure, for each row of my visual.

**At the same time**, these two year values of the slicer must remove the unwanted rows in my report visual, based on the slicer selection of year values.

For example, when the slicer has 2019 and 2020 chosen, I need the value as in the DesiredOutput1 page.

[image]

Similarly, you can see DesiredOutput2 (Slicer values are 2020 and 2022);   DesiredOutput3 (Slicer values are 2019 and 2022) pages.

[image]

[image]

I tried something like this:

```
Max_Year_Measure = MAXX(

                         ALLSELECTED(YearTable),

                         YearTable[Year]

                       )
```

**One main requirement**: the Year column of my main visual must come from YearTable, not from CountryTable; hence both the Year columns (one in the slicer, the other in the visual) are from YearTable only; this is a requirement, because I am using some RANKX function to filter out all rank values after 1, based on the slicer selection.

You can see this below:

```
Rank_FF_ASC_Measure = IF(

                              HASONEVALUE(YearTable[Year]) = TRUE,

                                  VAR Ranking = RANKX(

                                                       ALLSELECTED(YearTable[Year]),

                                                       CALCULATE(MAX(YearTable[YearOrder])),

                                                        ,

                                                       1,

                                                       SKIP

                                                     )

                                   RETURN Ranking,

                               BLANK()

                           )
```

**Note:**

In my client dataset, the Year values are prefixed with values such as Q1-2022, Q2-2022, etc. Hence I need to use YearTable[YearOrder] as the main sort column.

My eventual goal is to attain this visual below (when 2019 and 2020 are chosen in the slicer):

[image]

[image]

Or can [Rank_FF_ASC_Measure] be modified to meet my requirement ?

Any suggestion.

Please use the .pbix file in this posting. Feel free to reach out if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

First, I've modified the relationship between `YearTable`and `CountryTable`. In your file, the relationship is a *bi-directional many-to-many*.

I changed it to something more typical. It's a one-to-many from `YearTable` to `CountryTable`.

[image: something more typical]

In order to simplify the context. Here, `YearYable` filters `CountryTable` and not the other way around. Meaning that when you are in the row context of `CountryTable`, all selected rows in `YearTable` remains.

My first guess was to go for a simple measure like this:

```
MaxYear1 = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(YearTable[Year]),
    ALLSELECTED(CountryTable[Year])
)
```

But you don't get the expected result at visual level. Since it's able to calcule a value even for unselected rows, it returns them still.

[image: MaxYear1]

Note: I'm positive there is a proper workaround for this but couldn't find one.

So, I made a new measure:

```
MaxYear = 
MAXX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            CountryTable,
            CountryTable[Year]
        ),
        "MYear",
        MAX(YearTable[Year])
    ),
    [MYear]
)
```

The `ADDCOLUMNS/SUMMARIZE` is a [well documented practice](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/) of working a context by creating a kind of view within a measure. Maybe not it's best use here, but it works.

[image: MaxYear]

Comment: thanks very much; but what if my Year column in the visual comes from the YearTable ? This is a requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to have the Year column of the visual, from the YearTable that also feeds the slicer ?

Comment: The Year column of the visual must NOT be from the CountryTable  (I am okay with the 1-M relationship you have suggested; i did not notice the file before loading); there is a reason for my requirement; if this is not possible, I will explain another scenario which I need to address

Comment: i have added one more piece of requirement in my question, regarding the source of the Year column; is it possible to change your solution to match my requirement ?

Comment: I am okay with what you provided yesterday; thanks very much; if you can help me attain the final output - UltimateDesiredOutput1 - using the RANKX measure or some other measure, it would be great. (see the supplement to my question). When I choose 2019 and 2020 in the slicer, I need to show only the row value for 2019 in the Year column, and the [MaxYear_Measure_SlicerSelection] must be 2020. If this can be attained using the method you have suggested so far, please let me know.

Comment: I have an extension of this question posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735956/microsoft-power-bi-tricky-allselected-with-2-values-in-slicer-but-show-only-t

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a cartesian product when bringing in a measure is answered perfectly here: [Power BI slicer filtering not workin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806735/power-bi-slicer-filtering-not-workin)

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you need.

```
Measure = 
IF(
    ISEMPTY(CountryTable), 
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( YearTable[Year] ), ALLSELECTED ( YearTable[Year] ) )
)
```

Comment: thanks very much, appreciate it; I tried this; it works to the basic requirement; see the supplementary additions to my question (which I did not post until now), where I need to keep only one of the two rows in my UltimateDesiredOutput1.   I am using RANKX function (only in the visual filter, not in the visual itself) to keep only one of the two rows selected.  (the .pbix file has been updated with the RANKX measure)

Comment: This seems like a completely new question now. If I were you, I'd post a new question.

Comment: I did not realize this until now!!  I thought once I have the [MaxYear] measure, the [Rank_FF_ASC_Measure] measure (which already existed in my report)  will work automatically, unfortunately this is not the case

Comment: ok, will get back shortly

Comment: I have an extension of this question posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735956/microsoft-power-bi-tricky-allselected-with-2-values-in-slicer-but-show-only-t