# Matrix is displaying Cartesian product despite properly established relationships

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a fact table with sales figures, a customer table and a product table. And they are set up using the classic star schema where the fact table contains the date, sales, customer ID and product ID. And the dimension tables contain their respective IDs and names. I also created a calculated calendar table which has a relationship with the sales table via the date columns.

I created a simple measure to calculate the YTD sales, something like:

```
Sales YTD = CALCULATE (
                SUM ('Sales'[Sales]),
                DATESYTD ('Date'[Date])
              )
```

What you would expect to see, is that under each customer, only the products that they have purchased would be displayed. However, the problem I have is that under each customer, EVERY product is being displayed under them.
Let's say in the products table I have 100 distinct products and customer A only purchased 5 different products. This matrix is showing all 100 products under Customer A where 95 show $0 and the 5 that he actually purchased show the correct sales amount. And it does this for many of the customers, however a handful of customers correctly display only the products they've purchased (not sure if that gives you a hint as to what my problem is)

I have checked the tables, the relationships, the product and customer IDs and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my data model. Other reports I have created in the past with this same data model doesn't have this issue. I don't know if this helps in any way, but the data from the sales model is a direct query from SQL Server, but the product and customer table is simply excel data that I copied and pasted via the "Enter data" feature in PowerBI desktop.

Any help or suggestions would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: Add sample data, your expected output and what you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a cartesian product when bringing in a measure is answered perfectly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806735/power-bi-slicer-filtering-not-workin): Power BI slicer filtering not workin

Answer (score 0):

Can you please test this measure, and let me know If It solves your problem.

```
Sales YTD =
VAR TotalSales =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Sales'[Sales] ), DATESYTD ( 'Date'[Date] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( TotalSales > 0, TotalSales )
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to get rid of the error. Does that give you a clue as to what my issue was initially? I do have some sales figures that are negative so I amended the operator to <> and seems to work fine.

Comment: If you set your measure as [Total Sales] <> 0 , Then It will only show sales of products whose sales amount not equal to '0'; but The problem is that '<>0' expression will not fully protect you. Because It will take negative values into account. You need '>0' comparison operator.