# Power BI 101- Adding a measure to a table visual causes "duplicated" rows

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I guess this is a very basic power bi question but after spending some hours on the internet still haven't wrapped my head around this.

I have the most simple data model ever:
[image: data model]

and two calculated measures that count the distinct count of countries in each table:

## Country (Geo) = DISTINCTCOUNT(Geo[Country])

## Country (Sales) = DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[Country])

everything is visualized in the following tables:
[image]

What I'm struggling to understand is why in table 3, as soon as I add the # Countries(Geo) measure,
the visual starts repeating the rows matching each country from the Sales table to all countries in the Geography table.

I know it works if I use a crossfilter in that measure but I dont reallly understand why?

Could someone please explain what power bi is actually doing here or maybe point me to some documentation/article that deals with this concept?

This is a conceptual problem

Answer (score 1):

It's a frustrating and not particularly well documented feature.

The explanation as to why this occurs revolves around a feature know as 'auto-exist'. I have neither the time nor the knowledge to give a detailed description of that term (see [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/?platform=hootsuite), for example, if interested), suffice to sat that this feature only applies if columns from the same table are being used as filters: if columns from other tables are filtering the results, as in your case, then auto-exist does not apply, and, as you are witnessing in your example, a **cross-join operation** is instead employed.

I recall developing a workaround some time ago for such cases. If I manage to locate it I will add to this post.

Comment: The standard workaround is on the top post here Jos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806735/power-bi-slicer-filtering-not-workin

Comment: @DavidBacci Great stuff, thanks! I'll bookmark that one.